# Error when starting HDFS in Cloudera Manager - Address already in use when trying to bind to '/var/hdfs-sockets/dn'

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, cloudera-manager, datanode

I am getting error after installation and I am not able to start HDFS data node.

I am always getting Error:

> Exception in secureMain
> java.net.BindException: bind(2) error: Address already in use when trying to bind to '/var/hdfs-sockets/dn'
> at org.apache.hadoop.net.unix.DomainSocket.bind0(Native Method)
> at org.apache.hadoop.net.unix.DomainSocket.bindAndListen(DomainSocket.java:191)

I checked and with netstat I am not getting that something is busy on port 50010 since Data Node is run on 50010

Opened streaming server at /10.0.9.6:50010.

I tried by setting the parameter dfs.domain.socket.path to different paths:

/var/hdfs-sockets/dn

and

/var/hdfs-sockets

These folders are created on NameNode servers but also I created it on DataNode server.

I tried by setting it in the ownership of the root user but also and to cloudera-scm user.

And the same error is always thrown.

Can someone please provide me answer how to resolve this kind of error which is always thrown when trying to start HDFS since I am not able to continue further?

Comment: Did you fix this problem? I got a same thing. But I don't have any idea how I can fix it.

Comment: dont create last segment as a folder... /var/hdfs-sockets/dn  - var and hdfs-sockets should be folders and dn should be file and it  will be created automatically. in my example you just create var and hdfs-sockets as folders